# Endpoint that can be met at one visit and then not at the next

Tags: regression

I'm analysing an endpoint based on patient reported pain scored 1-3. When the patient gives a score of 1 the endpoint is met. Pain was assessed over 6 visits and it's possible that a patient could score 1 and then start experiencing pain and score 2-3 at the next visit or even score 1 at visits 1-5 and then 2-3 at the final visit 6. I'll be carrying out a time-to-event (Cox PH) regression analysis.

Issues with patient reported data aside, and other than with sensitivity analysis, does anyone have any suggestions for how this situation can be handled?

Thanks very much

Comment: Time to which event? From your explanation it seems like you want first occurrence of score = 1 ('endpoint met') which is a pretty straightforward analysis.